# Finding an equation of a quadratic function given 2 points?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, graphing-functions, cubics

I'm doing a maths problem in which a part of roller coaster track is missing. The gap must be filled by a polynomial equation and we know that it must smoothly connect with the points $(50,30)$ and $(100,0)$. At these points the gradient must be 0. The polynomials we have been doing are in the form $f(x)= A(x+a)(x+b)(x+c)$ etc.

So in summary I need an equation for a polynomial which goes exactly through $(50,30)$ and $(100,0)$

I think the equation must a cubic as we can then fill two of the parameters with $(x \pm100) $

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since you have four conditions for a polynomial, it must be a cubic.

Answer (score 1):

You're right if you want the function to have extreme points at $x=50$ and $x=100$, then it has to be at least of a third degree.

Now assume that $f(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$. Now as $(50,30)$ and $(100,0)$ lie on the graph of $f$ we have that $30 = f(50)$ and $0 = f(100)$. Now take the derivative of $f$, which is $f'(x) = 3Ax^2 + 2Bx + C$. Now as $(50,30)$ and $(100,0)$ are extreme points we must have $f'(50) = 0$ and $f'(100) = 0$. This four equations should help you determine the 4 variables $A,B,C,D$ and finaly the polynomial $f$.

Comment: I do not understand? How will the four equations help me?

Comment: @Plshelpwithmymaths You wil get a system of equations with 4 equations and 4 unknowns, which you should be able to solve

Comment: Are the four equations I need 1) 125000a+2500b+50c+d (2) 1000000a+10000b+100c+d (3)7500a+100b+c (4) 30000a+200b+c ?? if so what can I do with these equations

Comment: @Plshelpwithmymaths Yes they are the ones. But you need to equate them to $0$, except the first to $30$. Then solve the system of equation to get $A,B,C,D$